# Error creating Runnable jar in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a project that I'd like to make a Runnable Jar from.
I have a Run Configuration that works from within Eclipse.
When I try to Export a Runnable Jar, I get this error for every .jar the project uses:
"Fat Jar Export: Could not find class-path entry for "

Any ideas on what I need to do to make this work?

Comment: can you please post the complete error `Fat Jar Export: Could not find class-path entry for....` fill the dots. Because sometimes that error is related to mysql connector jar

Comment: You can check the class path by opening your jar file in WinRar. check META-INF/MANIFEST.MF in side jar.

Answer (score 5):

I had same problem, and solution is fairly easy. Just right-click to your project, select **Properties** -> **Java Build Path**, then open **Libraries** tab, click on **Add External JARs** and then select all of the libraries you need (the ones that you got the error message, in my case it was derbyclient.jar), confirm with **OK**. Then in Package Explorer you will get **Referenced Libraries** and there will be all of additional libraries that you need to export project into runnable JAR:

[image]

From unknown reasons Eclipse will not add them automatically even if you configured them properly in **Project** -> right click -> **Run As** -> **Run Configurations** -> **Classpath** tab. You have to add manually all of the libraries that you need with **Add External JARs**

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this issue by deleting the .project and .classpath, etc hidden files created by eclipse in my project directory. 
And then closing the project and importing the project a new.

I took 2 days to solve this.But this works!

Answer (score 0):

You can make your JAR executable by providing a Main-Class in the **META-INF/MANIFEST** file. You will need to make sure that all your dependencies are packaged into your JAR file, or you use an "uber jar" style solution.

See:

- http://csdl.ics.hawaii.edu/~johnson/613f99/modules/04/jar-files.html
- http://maven.apache.org/maven-1.x/plugins/uberjar/
- http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

is there any other JAR/library inside JAR file you are creating ? i

try to go through normal JAR wizard and add mian class through wizard. hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/pmw/tinylog/writers/Writer
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:56)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.pmw.tinylog.writers.Writer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 3 more
```

the solution for this was right click the project in eclipse, go to Properties then Java Build Path, then Order and Export and enable the Project and External Dependencies if it is disabled. Then export the runnable jar and it should contain any external libraries (you can verify this because it has a bigger size).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message but in a different situation, creating a runnable jar of a module in a multi module maven project.

The solution was to right click project > Maven > update project > select all modules and press OK. This will refresh the eclipse dependencies so that it matches the maven dependencies.